# Run chrome lighthouse's audit from command line

Tags: google-chrome, lighthouse

I would like to write a script which run (from the chrome's binary) its `lighthouse`'s audit with a url given.
I didn't manage to find how to do it, but since there is even a chrome extension doing I assume it should be feasible right ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google Lighthouse can be ran using the command line. To run it from the command line, you must first install:

- [Google Chrome for Desktop](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/)
- [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) v6 or later.

To install the Lighthouse CLI, open a command line and type the following command:

```sh
npm install -g lighthouse
```

To run an audit with Lighthouse, type:

```sh
lighthouse https://example.com
```

By default, Lighthouse writes the report to an HTML file. You can control the output format by passing [flags](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse#cli-options).

You will notice that a Chrome window is opened every time you run Lighthouse. If you don't want a window to be opened, you can run it in headless mode:

```sh
lighthouse https://example.com/ --chrome-flags="--headless"
```

For the complete list of options, type:

```sh
lighthouse --help
```

Take a look at the [Lighthouse source code repository](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) for additional documentation and examples.

Comment: I think you can use it without installing it globally: just create a `package.json` file in a folder, install lighthouse by running `npm install lighthouse` and run the commands from within that folder

Answer (score 1):

You can use/test via npx:

```
npm i npx -g
```

Then, directly run from your terminal without using a package.json created or installing globally & without opening a chrome browser instance:

```
npx lighthouse <URL> --only-categories="performance,seo,Accessibility" --chrome-flags="--headless"
```