# Monitor site's pages via lighthouse score in an automated way

Tags: monitoring, pagespeed, lighthouse

We have a task to gather lighthouse metrics periodically (once a minute for several pages)
We want to use pagespeed api.
Maybe there is payed version of it we can use in such case?
What is the price poilicy if it exists?

Thanks!

Comment: Once a minute seems a bit extreme. If hourly is frequent enough, PageSpeedPlus is a paid tool that monitors lighthouse scores on a schedule: https://pagespeedplus.com/blog/monitor-lighthouse-scores

Answer (score 1):

You can use paid services for it, for example, I'm working on pagespeed.green - scheduled tests will be supported soon. It would be beneficial to know your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you to integrate lighthouse with a reputed automation tool (like protractor) and audit your webpage through it. You can then run those lighthouse + protractor integrated test cases from jenkins/teamcity and periodically publish your report. In this way you can keep track of your website performance absolutely free.

And if you wonder how to integrate lighthouse with Protractor, you can refer [here](https://medium.com/@abhinabaghosh.1994/measure-your-websites-performance-with-google-lighthouse-and-protractor-1a6086267800).

Not only protractor, you can integrate lighthouse with puppeteer as well.

Let me know, if you get any success.

Answer (score 0):

check [Run chrome lighthouse's audit from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515808/run-chrome-lighthouses-audit-from-command-line) 
and run it on hot-reload, it will runs on any reloads. and you can add this to build script and check its values.